# C++ module crashes in Blender but not Python console

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I made a Python C++ module for optimizing a camera path. The linear algebra is done with the Eigen library and compiling for Python with pybind11.

I use my own camera model for calculations.

It worked well until I got to the point where I actually tried doing the optimization. The module does not rely on any calls to the Blender API so it can be used with pure Python as well. I just use Blender to setup the camera path and so on. In the Anaconda Python console, it runs without problems but when I call it in Blender, it always crashes Blender completely.

I had a look at the crash log, but cannot really make sense of it. I suspect this line `./blender(_ZN5Eigen8IOFormatD1Ev+0xd3) [0x2041673]` to be the culprit, because it might have something to do with the Eigen library and memory alignment but I am not sure because it generally works in Python.

Does someone has any idea why this happens? Can anyone help me make sense of the log?

Script (optFlowCam is my module)

```
import optFlowCam

cam1 = optFlowCam.Camera([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], 1)
cam2 = optFlowCam.Camera([2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], 1)
cam3 = optFlowCam.Camera([3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], 1)
cam4 = optFlowCam.Camera([4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], 1)

cams = [cam1, cam2, cam3, cam4]

def depth(ray):
    return 1

optimizedPath = optFlowCam.OpticalFlow.OptimizePath(cams, 10, 10, depth, 0.001, optFlowCam.OpticalFlow.OptimizationMethod.Solver)
```

crash log

```
# Blender 2.82 (sub 7), Commit date: 2020-03-12 05:06, Hash 375c7dc4caf4

# backtrace
./blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x1d) [0x6fbd4ad]
./blender() [0x1658449]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x46210) [0x7f443d0d8210]
./blender(_ZN5Eigen8IOFormatD1Ev+0xd3) [0x2041673]
/home/name/Programs/blender-2.82a-linux64/2.82/python/lib/python3.7/optFlowCam.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(_Z2_zRK6CameraRKN5Eigen6MatrixIdLi9ELi1ELi0ELi9ELi1EEEiiRKSt8functionIFdRK3RayEE+0x2d7) [0x7f441280de67]
/home/name/Programs/blender-2.82a-linux64/2.82/python/lib/python3.7/optFlowCam.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(_ZN11OpticalFlow13GradPathErrorERKSt6vectorI6CameraSaIS1_EEiiRKSt8functionIFdRK3RayEEd+0x562) [0x7f441280eb92]
/home/name/Programs/blender-2.82a-linux64/2.82/python/lib/python3.7/optFlowCam.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(_Z16_gradientDescentRKSt6vectorI6CameraSaIS0_EEiiRKSt8functionIFdRK3RayEEd+0x54b) [0x7f441281052b]
/home/name/Programs/blender-2.82a-linux64/2.82/python/lib/python3.7/optFlowCam.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(_ZN11OpticalFlow12OptimizePathERKSt6vectorI6CameraSaIS1_EEiiRKSt8functionIFdRK3RayEEdNS_18OptimizationMethodE+0x22) [0x7f4412810be2]
/home/name/Programs/blender-2.82a-linux64/2.82/python/lib/python3.7/optFlowCam.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x3d910) [0x7f4412808910]
/home/name/Programs/blender-2.82a-linux64/2.82/python/lib/python3.7/optFlowCam.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x317ed) [0x7f44127fc7ed]
./blender(_PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords+0x2f3) [0x5d48aa3]
./blender(_PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords+0x25) [0x5d48b25]
./blender(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x7468) [0x1652c38]
./blender(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0xadc) [0x5dfa4bc]
./blender(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x3e) [0x5dfa5ee]
./blender(PyEval_EvalCode+0x1b) [0x5dfa61b]
./blender() [0x1b3d98c]
./blender() [0x1f1e11e]
./blender() [0x1820a8b]
./blender() [0x1820cf7]
./blender(WM_operator_name_call_ptr+0x1a) [0x18210fa]
./blender() [0x1e11e02]
./blender() [0x1e21d15]
./blender() [0x1823b53]
./blender() [0x182590c]
./blender(wm_event_do_handlers+0x312) [0x1825fe2]
./blender(WM_main+0x20) [0x181c200]
./blender(main+0x317) [0x159ea77]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7f443d0b90b3]
./blender() [0x1654cfc]
```

**Edit:**

With faulthandler.enable(), I get

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007fa5fab18040 (most recent call first):
  File "/Text", line 16 in <module>
```

so it definitely is a memory issue of some sort.

The module is compile for Python 3.7. The Anaconda console uses Python 3.7.5 and Blender uses 3.7.4.
The module code is lengthy (multiple files) and not publicly available. I copy the compiled module into the
`<blender Version>/python/lib/python3.7` folder to load it.

Comment: Is your module compiled against same python version (major dot minor) as blender?  How is it made available to import into blender.  Module code?

Comment: I edited my post. The module code is quiet long, so I definitley cannot include everything. It seems to be a memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved.

This line `./blender(_ZN5Eigen8IOFormatD1Ev+0xd3) [0x2041673]` actually *was* the culprit. I debugged again using gdb and looked at the stacktrace there. This is the same line but from the gdb backtrace `#0  0x0000000002041673 in Eigen::IOFormat::~IOFormat() ()`.

The problem was I used `Eigen::IOFormat HeavyMtxFmt(Eigen::FullPrecision, 0, ", ", ",\n", "[", "]", "[", "]");` in my program to debug print the matrices and vectors for easier copying into another program where I just wanted to check if the values are correct. Apparently that was the cause for this debug session instead. I removed it, recompiled and now the program is running through.

Comment: Happy you have solved your issue. Have voted to close question, as it is only applicable to those with access to the  "not publicly available" source.